# location permission popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I'm making a web browser in PyQt5 and Python. How to make location permission popup like the following:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets,QtWebEngine
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from threading import Timer
import re
import urllib.request


class SearchPanel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    searched = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.FindFlag)
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.case_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Match &Case', checkable=True)
        next_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Next')
        prev_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Previous')
        self.search_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.setFocusProxy(self.search_le)

        next_button.clicked.connect(self.update_searching)
        prev_button.clicked.connect(self.on_preview_find)
        self.case_button.clicked.connect(self.update_searching)
        for btn in (self.case_button, self.search_le, next_button, prev_button, ):
            lay.addWidget(btn)
            if isinstance(btn, QtWidgets.QPushButton): btn.clicked.connect(self.setFocus)
        self.search_le.textChanged.connect(self.update_searching)
        self.search_le.returnPressed.connect(self.update_searching)
        self.closed.connect(self.search_le.clear)

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.FindNext, self, activated=next_button.animateClick)
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.FindPrevious, self, activated=prev_button.animateClick)
        QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape), self.search_le, activated=self.closed)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_preview_find(self):
        self.update_searching(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.FindBackward)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_searching(self, direction=QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.FindFlag()):
        flag = direction
        if self.case_button.isChecked():
            flag |= QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.FindCaseSensitively
        self.searched.emit(self.search_le.text(), flag)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super(SearchPanel, self).showEvent(event)
        self.setFocus(True)

class AboutDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        QBtn = QDialogButtonBox.Ok  # No cancel
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        title = QLabel("Pyxis Browser")
        font = title.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        title.setFont(font)

        layout.addWidget(title)

        logo = QLabel()
        logo.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('', 'ma-icon-128.png')))
        layout.addWidget(logo)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Version 1.0.0"))
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Copyright."))

        for i in range(0, layout.count()):
            layout.itemAt(i).setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class MyPage(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def triggerAction(self, action, checked=False):
        if action == QWebEnginePage.OpenLinkInNewWindow:
            self.createWindow(QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserWindow)

        return super(MyPage, self).triggerAction(action, checked)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://androidd.pw/Login/"))
        QWebEnginePage.JavascriptCanOpenWindows:True

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.page_loading)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        #self.browser.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowGeolocationOnInsecureOrigins, True)

        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        navtb.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.addToolBar(navtb)

        guide = QToolBar("Navigation")
        guide.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.addToolBar(guide)

        self.guidestate = QLabel()  # Yes, really!
        self.guidestate.setText('Welcome to Pyxis Ad')

        font = self.guidestate.font()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.guidestate.setFont(font)
        guide.addWidget(self.guidestate)

        self.done_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'done.png')), "Done", self)
        self.done_btn.setVisible(False)
        self.done_btn.triggered.connect(self.start_earning)
        guide.addAction(self.done_btn)

        self.child_domain = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'new_ad.png')), "Load New Pyxis Domain", self)
        self.child_domain.setVisible(False)
        self.child_domain.triggered.connect(self.load_child_domain)
        guide.addAction(self.child_domain)

        self.advertise = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'new_ad.png')), "Load New Avertisements Site", self)
        self.advertise.setVisible(False)
        self.advertise.triggered.connect(self.load_advertise)
        guide.addAction(self.advertise)

        self.load_new_url = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'new_ad.png')), "Reload New Site", self)
        self.load_new_url.setVisible(False)
        self.load_new_url.triggered.connect(self.new_ad_site)
        guide.addAction(self.load_new_url)

        back_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'arrow-180.png')), "Back", self)
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)

        next_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'arrow-000.png')), "Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'arrow-circle-315.png')), "Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'home.png')), "Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        navtb.addSeparator()

        self.httpsicon = QLabel()  # Yes, really!
        self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('', 'lock-nossl.png')))
        navtb.addWidget(self.httpsicon)

        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
        #self.urlbar.setDisabled(1)
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)
        QWebEnginePage.JavascriptCanOpenWindows:True

        stop_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'cross-circle.png')), "Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.stop)
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Help")

        about_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'question.png')), "About Browser", self)
        about_action.setStatusTip("Find out more about Pyxis Browser")  # Hungry!
        about_action.triggered.connect(self.about)
        help_menu.addAction(about_action)

        navigate_mozarella_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'lifebuoy.png')), "Pyxis Homepage", self)
        navigate_mozarella_action.setStatusTip("Go to Browser Homepage")
        navigate_mozarella_action.triggered.connect(self.navigate_mozarella)
        help_menu.addAction(navigate_mozarella_action)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('', 'ma-icon-64.png')))


    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("%s - Pyxis" % title)

    def page_loading(self):

        title = 'Loading...'
        self.setWindowTitle("%s - Pyxis" % title)

    def navigate_mozarella(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://androidd.pw"))

    def about(self):
        dlg = AboutDialog()
        dlg.exec_()

    def print_page(self):
        dlg = QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dlg.paintRequested.connect(self.browser.print_)
        dlg.exec_()

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://androidd.pw"))

    def start_earning(self):

        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://androidd.pw/API/legal_click"))

    def load_child_domain(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://androidd.pw/API/getRandom/general'))

    def load_advertise(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://androidd.pw/API/getRandom/ads'))

    def navigate_to_url(self):  # Does not receive the Url
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
        if q.scheme() == "":
            q.setScheme("http")

        self.browser.setUrl(q)

    def timeout(self):
        self.guidestate.setText('Ad Completed')
        self.done_btn.setVisible(True)
        self.load_new_url.setVisible(False)

    def new_ad_site(self):
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/single_site") as single_url:single = single_url.read()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(single.decode('utf-8')))

    def update_urlbar(self, q):
        ###################################################################################
        url = q.host()

        #http://ipackersmovers.com/API/url/general?url=http://www.firsttecnology.us


        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/url/general?url="+url) as pyxis_url:pyxis = pyxis_url.read()
        with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/url/ads?url="+url) as dom_url:ad = dom_url.read()
        #with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/save/60c1e7acb990ce54bf7d496dc4936865") as ad_click:click = ad_click.read()

        if pyxis == b'0':
            pyxis = False
        else:
            pyxis = True

        if ad == b'0':
            ad = False
        else:
            ad = True

        if pyxis:
            self.guidestate.setText('Welcome to Pyxis Ad | You are currently on working area')
            self.done_btn.setVisible(False)
            self.load_new_url.setVisible(False)
            self.child_domain.setVisible(False)
            self.advertise.setVisible(False)
        elif ad:
            self.guidestate.setText('Click On Adsense Ad | if Ads are not visible then Reload new site =>')
            self.done_btn.setVisible(False)
            self.load_new_url.setVisible(True)
            self.child_domain.setVisible(False)
            self.advertise.setVisible(False)

        elif q.host() == 'www.google.com' or q.host() == 'google.com':

            query_url = q.query()

            if re.search("^q=.*&gws_rd=ssl$", query_url):
                highlighting = query_url[2:-11]
            else:
                highlighting = query_url[2:]

            with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/url/general?url="+highlighting) as pyxis_url:pyxis_child = pyxis_url.read()
            with urllib.request.urlopen("http://androidd.pw/API/url/ads?url="+highlighting) as dom_url:advert = dom_url.read()
            self.guidestate.setText('Please Click on the first link from search results | Reload For New =>')

            if pyxis_child.decode('utf-8'):
                self.child_domain.setVisible(True)
            elif advert.decode('utf-8'):
                self.advertise.setVisible(True)

            self.done_btn.setVisible(False)
            self.load_new_url.setVisible(False)

            direction=QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.FindFlag()
            self.browser.findText(highlighting, direction)

        else:
            self.guidestate.setText('Please wait...')
            self.done_btn.setVisible(False)
            self.load_new_url.setVisible(False)
            self.child_domain.setVisible(False)
            self.advertise.setVisible(False)
            # duration is in seconds
            t = Timer(25, self.timeout)
            t.start()


        ############################Checking which site is on###############################

        if q.scheme() == 'https':
            # Secure padlock icon
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'lock-ssl.png')))

        else:
            # Insecure padlock icon
            self.httpsicon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join('images', 'lock-nossl.png')))

        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)


    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            self.browser = MainWindow()
            self.browser.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            self.browser.show()
            return self.browser
        return super(MainWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Pyxis")
    app.setOrganizationName("Pyxis")
    app.setOrganizationDomain("Pyxis")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `featurePermissionRequested` signal that will be issued every time the browser requires permissions to use some resource, then open a dialog and if the user accepts or not then use `setFeaturePermission()` to accept or deny the feature:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.featurePermissionRequested.connect(self.handleFeaturePermissionRequested)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QUrl, QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.Feature)
    def handleFeaturePermissionRequested(self, securityOrigin, feature):
        title = "Permission Request"
        questionForFeature = {
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.Geolocation : "Allow {feature} to access your location information?",
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.MediaAudioCapture : "Allow {feature} to access your microphone?",
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.MediaVideoCapture : "Allow {feature} to access your webcam?",
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.MediaAudioVideoCapture : "Allow {feature} to lock your mouse cursor?",
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.DesktopVideoCapture : "Allow {feature} to capture video of your desktop?",
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.DesktopAudioVideoCapture: "Allow {feature} to capture audio and video of your desktop?"
        }
        question = questionForFeature.get(feature)
        if question:
            question = question.format(feature=securityOrigin.host())
            if QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self.view().window(), title, question) == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                self.setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.PermissionGrantedByUser)
            else:
                self.setFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.PermissionDeniedByUser)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        page = WebEnginePage(self.browser)
        self.browser.setPage(page)
        self.browser.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply  but it's denying permission every time. I mean when I click "Yes" allow location permission it showing error.


serialnmea: No known GPS device found. Specify the COM port via QT_NMEA_SERIAL_PORT.
Failed to create Geoclue client interface. Geoclue error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem That is a problem because you need a location provider, now Qt uses geoclue or geoclue2, what is your OS?

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem If you are using ubuntu test installing: `sudo apt-get install libgeoclue-dev geoclue`

Comment: I'm using windows 10 64bit OS

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtpositioning-index.html):  *Currently the API is supported on Android, iOS, macOS, Linux (using GeoClue version 0.12.99), **Windows (with GPS receivers exposed as a serial port providing NMEA sentences)**, and WinRT (using Windows.Devices.Geolocation)*, that is, you need to have a GPS connected through a serial port.

Comment: okay that means I have to install ubantu and then it will work. Right?

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem It should work, obviously you should install the dependencies as geoclue with the command that points you, I'm using linux and if you can get my geolocation. If you are going to install PyQt5 on ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev qtlocation5-dev`